# How to configure sonarqube msbuild scanner

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am checking the [documentation for sonarqube msbuild scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild). But I can't find the `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe` in the distribution given. So when I point the bin directory and run sonar command given in that page

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

I got an error saying

```
'SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Since this exe file is not in the distribution and it runs using `sonar-scanner` bat file what is the correct command to run the project?
When I using `sonar-scanner` instead of `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe`, it complains about `/k` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the latest version of [SonarScanner for MsBuild](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases). The zip file contains all needed executables.

You should not use `sonar-scanner` for analyzing .NET projects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. It seems like distribution should be updated pointed in the document.